# Повтор элементов в массиве js

Tags: javascript

вот код:

```
let arrayNums = [3, 7, 9, 4, 6, 1, 1]

let check = function(array = [])
{ 
  bool = false
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {
    let removedNum = array.shift()
    if (array.includes(removedNum))
    {
      bool = true
      break
    }
  }

  if (bool)
    return 'содержит похожие элементы'
  else 
    return 'не содержит похожие элементы'
}

console.log(check(arrayNums))
```

Почему мне выдает не содержит похожие элементы? алгоритм вроде верный

Comment: "алгоритм вроде верный" --- чтобы не гадать - воспользуйся отладкой (см. дубликат)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, теперь разобрался с помощью отладчика, он выходил из цикла, но не давал переменной bool значение true, потому что я забыл написать let bool)

Comment:  ...ну хоть кто-то меня не обозвал му** и не послал а действительно воспользовался отладкой 